# All the same vs all one

Tags: phrases, exam-questions

This is a sentence improvement question asked in my exam :

> It is **all but same** to me whether I am transferred to Canada or USA.

I have four options to choose from to replace the bold part

A) all or same

B) all the same

C) all one

D) no improvement

If I go by meaning then both options - B and C mean same so considering the structure of the sentence which option is correct here and why ? I am not able to decide between these two options as the meaning given in dictionary is same for both.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tough question, if there is supposed to be only one correct answer.  Both B and C do indeed have the same meaning.  Americans use B.  I haven't lived in England for 45 years, but I seem to remember hearing "It's all one to me" there.  Perhaps someone more familiar with BrE would care to weigh in.

If I were taking the test, I would choose B.

Comment: I'm a born and raised Brit, and my first thought on seeing this question was "perhaps it's all one to me is an American phrase".  I've never heard it in my life, and I'm English... Having just googled it apparently it does exists, but I would guess that perhaps the person who wrote the question had never heard "it's all one to me" either, and so didn't realise that was also a correct answer.

Comment: @Some_Guy I never hear it here in America, either. It looks like B is the best choice.